# Android Studio - How to load data into the app when the app first launch?

Tags: java, android-studio, fragment

I have an application that contain some fragment for swiping purpose. And on one of the fragment, user can type in their name, and after typing it, the app will save their data with FileOutputStream.

Then, everytime user launch the app, I want to use FileInputStream to get the data and display the data.

The problem is, I think I'm wrong for implementing FileInputStream into public View onCreateView(), because my app crash everytime I try to run it after I implement the codes into public View onCreateView(), there's no error, there's nothing to show on event log, it just crash. Below is my fragment,java

```
package layout;


import ...;

public class page1 extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final EditText text = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.p1Name);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileinputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("page1name.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputstreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileinputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String lines;
        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            stringBuffer.append(lines+"\n");
        }
        text.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container,
            false);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final EditText text = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.p1Name);


    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String p1sName = s.toString();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileoutputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput( "page1name.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fileoutputStream.write(p1sName.getBytes());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Therefore, I would like to know, Where should I implement FileInputStream in order to get it working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using FileInputStream, you can save in preferences

like

```
public static void saveName(Context context, String name) {
    SecureSharedPreferences sharedPreferences = new SecureSharedPreferences(context);
    SecureSharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
    ed.putString("name", name);
    ed.commit();
}

 public static String getName(Context context) {
    SecureSharedPreferences sharedPreferences = new SecureSharedPreferences(context);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", null);
    return name;
}
```

If you want to save in file using FileInputStream , you need to use AsyncTask, in your code you are doing background operation in main thread which is restricted

Comment: Thanks for replying! Will try it out asap!